# how to implement a custom camera with buttons?

Tags: android, button, android-camera

I want to develop an application with a **custom camera** with one **button** over it. when i click on that **button** the picture should be clicked. once the picture is clicked there should be two buttons **'save' and 'retake'**. If i click on **save** button the captured image should be saved to specified directory. if i click on **retake** button it should navigate to previous screen(camera with button).

I have gone through many sites and links.but nothing helped me.please help me..

Comment: You have obviously not looked hard enough, no one here is just going to give you a free camera app. Here is the camera API link, though: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: i just want an idea about this...

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html

Comment: +Josh the OP did not ask for a free camera app. He asked HOW do you go about implementing one, clearly implying providing resources. In fact, I spent hours trying to figure out how snapchat does it, and some of the links on this page were helpful. So once again, these are unwarranted downvotes. I notice how mainly Android questions get a high number of unwarranted downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) link. You'll get a basic idea as to how to go about creating a custom camera app. Once you've assigned the [image capture intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image%22image%20capture%20intent%22) to the capture button, then you can go ahead. Suggest you to take one step at a time if you're new to Android. You can find more info on building Camera apps [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html).